# What is wrong with my if statement inside Django Template?

Tags: django, django-templates

Inside a template, I have introduced this line of code.

```
{% if inbox_count == 0 %}No Messages{% else %}New Messages{% endif %}
```

It is showing 'New Messages' even though printing inbox_count shows 0.

At the top of the template, I have {% load inbox %}

Here is the actual template tag:

```
from django.template import Library, Node, TemplateSyntaxError

class InboxOutput(Node):
    def __init__(self, varname=None):
        self.varname = varname

    def render(self, context):
        try:
            user = context['user']
            count = user.received_messages.filter(read_at__isnull=True, recipient_deleted_at__isnull=True).count()
        except (KeyError, AttributeError):
            count = ''
        if self.varname is not None:
            context[self.varname] = count
            return ""
        else:
            return count        

def do_print_inbox_count(parser, token):
    """
    A templatetag to show the unread-count for a logged in user.
    Returns the number of unread messages in the user's inbox.
    Usage::

        {% load inbox %}
        {% inbox_count %}

        {# or assign the value to a variable: #}

        {% inbox_count as my_var %}
        {{ my_var }}

    """
    bits = token.contents.split()
    if len(bits) > 1:
        if len(bits) != 3:
            raise TemplateSyntaxError("inbox_count tag takes either no arguments or exactly two arguments")
        if bits[1] != 'as':
            raise TemplateSyntaxError, "first argument to inbox_count tag must be 'as'"
        return InboxOutput(bits[2])
    else:
        return InboxOutput()

register = Library()     
register.tag('inbox_count', do_print_inbox_count)
```

Is this returning a string ?

Comment: Have you tried `== 0`?

Comment: Isn't inbox_count a string?

Comment: If you print out `print inbox_count, type(inbox_count)` in your views what do you get?

Comment: oh good idea, let me try

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to do that, but I just pasted the entire template tag.

Comment: Okay, if you print `count` BEFORE this line (`if self.varname is not None:`), what do you get?

Comment: it prints 0.  So why does  {% if inbox_count == 0 %} not work?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `{% if not inbox_count %}`:

```
{% if not inbox_count %}No Messages{% else %}New Messages{% endif %}
```

Also make sure there is a space between the between `inbox_count` and the operator `=` and the also space between `=` and numerical value `0`. As this `inbox_count=0` will cause `TemplateSyntaxError`:

> Could not parse the remainder: '==0' from 'inbox_count==0''

So the code should be like this:

```
{% if inbox_count == 0 %}No Messages{% else %}New Messages{% endif %}
```

**Update:**

```
[...]

def render(self, context):
    count = 0
    try:
        user = context['user']
        count = user.received_messages.filter(read_at__isnull=True, recipient_deleted_at__isnull=True).count()
    except (KeyError, AttributeError):
        pass

    if self.varname is not None:
        context[self.varname] = count

    return count
```

Comment: I updated my post, the error is gone, but it keeps saying "New Messages" even though {% inbox_count %} shows 0.

Comment: You still need a space between `==` and `0`

Comment: sorry that was a typo, I do have the space.

Comment: Without knowing what generates `inbox_count` etc. I can't really help you debug that problem. Please make sure that `inbox_count` is a number.

Comment: I added the entire template tag for inbox_count, from looking at it.

Comment: `inbox_count` is a string! You need to return a number.

Comment: do i just change return "%s" & (count) ?

Comment: just return the actual count var. so `return count`

Comment: I update the template tag to show the change I made but it is still not working for me.

Comment: do i need to return count for both the if/then statements?